# "SQL agent" vs "SQL client"

Tags: sql

According "Part 1: Framework (SQL/Framework)" in ANSII SQL:2008 there are two concepts:

"SQL-agent" and "SQL-client".

Here are the definitions for both:

1) For "SQL-agent" (see section 4.2.2):

> An SQL-agent is that which causes the execution of SQL-statements

2) "SQL-client" (see section 4.2.3.1)

> An SQL-client is a processor, perceived by the SQL-agent as part of
>   the SQL-implementation, that establishes SQL-connections between
>   itself and SQL-servers and maintains a diagnostics area and other
>   state data relating to interactions between itself, the SQL-agent, and
>   the SQL-servers.

What is the differences among them?

And can you give an example of both for particular DB vendor (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Simply an SQL Agent is a user program that interacts with the DBMS either through a SQL Client or directly. See for instance section “4.8 Communication between an SQL-agent and an SQL-server”, where it is said:

> A host language is a programming language that can be used to write an SQL-agent. For an SQL-implementation to communicate successfully with an SQL-agent, the latter must be written using a host language supported by the SQL-implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Renzo.

I just want to expand your answer.

SQL-Clients is a part of DBMS that produce SQL-statements.
It can have UI like "Query Analizer" in SQL Server 2000
or just like a Console Editor like "SQL*Plus" in Oracle.

On the other hand SQL-server (also mentioned in the spec)
is a part of DBMS that consumes SQL-statements.

A prime example of this is a SQL Server Installation Wizard.
On one of the steps of this wizard we can choose what we want to install:

1) Client tools only

2) Server tools only

3) Client and Server tools

SQL-agent is a user program that connects to DBMS.
For example, for Java it can be standalone Java application that connects to the database via JDBC.